# Reading each word from a file into a char array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

What is the correct way of reading in a file using `ifstream()` and then storing each word in an a char array? This char array will eventually be used to input the current word into a hash table.

My code:

```
int main()
{
  int array_size = 4096; 
    char * filecontents = new char[array_size]; 
    char * word = new char[16];
    int position = 0; 
    ifstream fin("Dict.txt"); 

  if(fin.is_open())
    {

    cout << "File Opened successfully" << endl;
        while(!fin.eof() && position < array_size)
        {
            fin.get(filecontents[position]); 
            position++;
        }
        filecontents[position-1] = '\0';

        for(int i = 0; filecontents[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            word[i] = filecontents[i];
            //insert into hash table
            word[i] = ' ';

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The correct way would be to read the file into a `std::vector` of `std::strings` as this is C++

Comment: You **always** need to check **after** reading if the operation was successful: before trying to read the stream won't know what you are going to try and there is no way to determine if that attempt is going to be successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a char array unless you absolutely have to. Read them into strings, and toss the strings into your hashtable. If you don't have a hashtable, may I recommend [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)? Probably right in line with what you need.

Reading stuff. Give this a try:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("Dict.txt");
    set<string> dict;  // using set as a hashtable place holder.

    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File Opened successfully" << endl;
        string word;
        while (getline(fin, word, '\0'))
        {  /* getline normally gets lines until the file can't be read, 
                but you can swap looking for EOL with pretty much anything 
                else. Null in this case because OP was looking for null */
           //insert into hash table
            dict.insert(word); //putting word into set
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
    }
    system("pause"); // recommend something like cin >> some_junk_variable
    return 0;
}
```